# How to self union a GeoDataFrame?

Tags: python, geopandas, union

I have a GeoPandas dataframe with lines all originating in the same location. I want to partition the lines into segments and merge them to get a dataframe containing all the unique segments.

I tried overlay with union, which seems to solve my described problem. However, this only supports polygons. I am looking for a solution lines.

[image]

```
import geopandas as gpd

lines_gdf = gpd.read_file('input.geojson')
lines_union_gdf = gpd.overlay(lines_gdf, lines_gdf, how='union')
```

[image]

Example input file: [input.geojson](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e5db757f4340ce962e8af93b7c4de23c)

Expected output file: [output.geojson](https://gist.github.com/ustroetz/15315fa325e50c30de7e0afb77e31a06)

Comment: Can your provide a small reproducible example (eg dataframe with 3 LineStrings) and the desired result for that?

Comment: I added some sample data and sample code. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: In case someone is looking for the solution to the problem with PostGIS: 
`SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Node(ST_Collect(geom)))).geom as geom FROM table`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the geometry you can use the [unary_union](http://geopandas.org/reference.html?highlight=union#GeoSeries.unary_union) ([Shapely unary_union](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union)) predicate. The method will split all self-intersection geometries ([Planar Graph)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)

```
# unary union of all the geometries of the GeoDataFrame
lines_gdf.geometry.unary_union
<shapely.geometry.multilinestring.MultiLineString object at 0x10cc20e10>
lines_gdf.geometry.unary_union.wkt
'MULTILINESTRING ((13.39825630187988 52.50709252547882, 13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911), (13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911, 13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842), (13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842, 13.40799808502197 52.50440198101236), (13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842, 13.40608835220337 52.50564278654393), (13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911, 13.40445756912231 52.50790226875552))'
 for geom in lines_gdf.geometry.unary_union:
     print(geom)
 LINESTRING (13.39825630187988 52.50709252547882, 13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911)
 LINESTRING (13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911, 13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842)
 LINESTRING (13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842, 13.40799808502197 52.50440198101236)
 LINESTRING (13.40518712997437 52.50513340745842, 13.40608835220337 52.50564278654393)
 LINESTRING (13.40160369873047 52.50617828126911, 13.40445756912231 52.50790226875552)
```

[image]

Comment: can you also think of a solution where I don't loose all attributes? see my question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/380054/95730

Answer (score 0):

In general, the accepted answer should work, but for my dataset, it did not. Calling `unary_union` and iterating over the `geoms` resulted in many lines that were split between intersections. See below, the thin blue lines are the original dataset, and the colors show a subset of segments after running the above procedure. The expected behavior is that the blue, orange, and green segments at the bottom comprise a single segment instead of three separate ones (and the purple and red are combined, etc.).

[image]

I found a function `remove_false_nodes` from the `momepy` module, [documentation here](https://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/generated/momepy.remove_false_nodes.html). This function takes a GeoDataFrame as input (such as the one I've plotted a sample of above) and dissolves these extra lines such that we get the desired result (the blue, orange, and green lines would become a single `LineString`). Note that if no such dissolves need to be made, this function is simply the identity function, so I'd recommend incorporating this into your workflow by default.