# Why gdf.explode() doesn't work?

Tags: geopandas, union, explode, geodataframe

I'm trying to merge 2 geodataframes and combine all entities.
So I use :

```
cloudNshadow = gpd.overlay(cloud, shadow, how='union')
cloudNshadow = cloudNshadow.unary_union()
```

But it returns me :

```
cloudNshadow = cloudNshadow.unary_union()
TypeError: 'MultiPolygon' object is not callable
```

So I insert a gdf.explode() :

```
cloudNshadow = gpd.overlay(cloud, shadow, how='union')
cloudNshadow = cloudNshadow.explode()
cloudNshadow = cloudNshadow.unary_union()
```

But same error...
Explode() isn't supposed to explode multi-entities ??

Comment: `unary_union` is a property, not a method, so you can do `cloudNshadow.unary_union` instead of `cloudNshadow.unary_union()`

Comment: Damn ! you're right

Comment: @joris But i'm still stucked by multipolygon. it doesn't work with `gdf.to_file('gdf.shp)` : `AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'to_file'`

Comment: That's because a MultiPolygon is a single scalar geometry object (a shapely object), not a GeoDataFrame which has a `to_file` method. If you want to export it to a file, you need to put it again in a GeoDataFrame

Comment: Somewhere in your script, you might have assigned `gpd` variable to `MultiPolygon` object or a method returning `Multipolygon` instead of `GeoDataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Look at [How to self union a GeoDataFrame?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/274783). [unary_union](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) is a Shapely function (GeoPandas uses Shapely)

With the example of GeoPandas ([Set-Operations with Overlay](http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html))

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
polys1 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)]),Polygon([(2,2), (4,2), (4,4), (2,4)])])
polys2 = gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(1,1), (3,1), (3,3), (1,3)]),Polygon([(3,3), (5,3), (5,5), (3,5)])])
df1 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': poly1, 'df1':[1,2]})
df2 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': polys2, 'df2':[1,2]})
# merge the two GeoDataframe
cloudNshadow = gpd.overlay(df1, df2, how='union')
print(cloudNshadow)
   df1  df2                          geometry
0  1.0  NaN            POLYGON ((2 1, 2 0, 0 0, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 2 1))
1  1.0  1.0            POLYGON ((2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1))
2  NaN  1.0            POLYGON ((2 1, 2 2, 3 2, 3 1, 2 1))
3  NaN  1.0            POLYGON ((2 2, 1 2, 1 3, 2 3, 2 2))
4  2.0  NaN            POLYGON ((3 2, 3 3, 4 3, 4 2, 3 2))
5  2.0  1.0            POLYGON ((3 3, 3 2, 2 2, 2 3, 3 3))
6  2.0  NaN            POLYGON ((3 3, 2 3, 2 4, 3 4, 3 3))
7  NaN  2.0            POLYGON ((4 3, 4 4, 3 4, 3 5, 5 5, 5 3, 4 3))
8  2.0  2.0            POLYGON ((3 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3, 3 4))
```

Now, to apply unary_union you need a shapely geometry not a GeoDataFrame

```
print(cloudNshadow.geometry.unary_union.wkt) 
POLYGON ((2 1, 2 0, 0 0, 0 2, 1 2, 1 3, 2 3, 2 4, 3 4, 3 5, 5 5, 5 3, 4 3, 4 2, 3 2, 3 1, 2 1))
```

and same for explode()

```
# creation of a MuliPolygon
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon
multi = MultiPolygon(poly for poly in  cloudNshadow.geometry)
print(multi) 
MULTIPOLYGON (((2 1, 2 0, 0 0, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 2 1)), ((2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1)), ((2 1, 2 2, 3 2, 3 1, 2 1)), ((2 2, 1 2, 1 3, 2 3, 2 2)), ((3 2, 3 3, 4 3, 4 2, 3 2)), ((3 3, 3 2, 2 2, 2 3, 3 3)), ((3 3, 2 3, 2 4, 3 4, 3 3)), ((4 3, 4 4, 3 4, 3 5, 5 5, 5 3, 4 3)), ((3 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3, 3 4)))
multigs = gpd.GeoSeries(multi)
df3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': multigs, 'test':[1]})
print( df3.geometry.explode())
0      POLYGON ((2 1, 2 0, 0 0, 0 2, 1 2, 1 1, 2 1))
1      POLYGON ((2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1))
2      POLYGON ((2 1, 2 2, 3 2, 3 1, 2 1))
3      POLYGON ((2 2, 1 2, 1 3, 2 3, 2 2))
4      POLYGON ((3 2, 3 3, 4 3, 4 2, 3 2))
5      POLYGON ((3 3, 3 2, 2 2, 2 3, 3 3))
6      POLYGON ((3 3, 2 3, 2 4, 3 4, 3 3))
7      POLYGON ((4 3, 4 4, 3 4, 3 5, 5 5, 5 3, 4 3))
8      POLYGON ((3 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3, 3 4))
Name: geometry, dtype: object
```